# Interactive maps for a survey - Are there any tools yet?

Tags: google-maps, web-mapping, maps, land-survey

i am working on a draft for an online-based survey. I would like to enable the participants of the survey to draw polygons, lines and points (several) on a basemap (e.g. google maps) and (extra feature) additionally to comment on these elements. Each element drawn by one participant should be stored.

I am looking for a ready-to-use method/tool to embed it in the survey. Right now, a fully costumized solution is not an option. Unfortunately, i couldn't find a suitable tool yet.

The whole idea is more or less a mental map, an interactive tool to highlight topographic elements on a basemap.

If you know some possible solutions or tools to meet my requirements, i would appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks,
J

Comment: I am finding myself in the same position now. Has anything changed, any new solutions available? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API v3 added a [Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing) sometime last year; users can create any kind of singular geometry by drawing on the map. Unfortunately, it doesn't natively support adding comments or any kind of attribution, but if you were developing a Maps API application you could listen for the "overlaycomplete" event(s) (e.g. polygoncomplete, linecomplete) to determine when to grab the user-defined geometry, annotate it, and store it/send it to a server. [Leaflet also has a drawing library](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw), available as a plugin.

For a low-tech solution, have you considered [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables)? Designated users can collaborate on geographic data through an interactive map interface.

Comment: Hi Arthur. Thanks for our suggestions. I've been working with Google Fusion Tables so far. Drawing Library and Leaflet seem to be more customizable and therefore better for my purpose. Thank you. I'll give it a try.